# Mapping from a unit square to a unit circle (and more generally to an ellipse)

Tags: functions

I was wondering how you can map a unit square (with vertices (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (0,0) ) to a unit circle.

More generally, how can I map a unit square to an ellipse centered at the origin?

Please note that my square lies only in the first quadrant and has an area 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, inscribe a circle in the square, and project each point on the square radially. To get an ellipse, expand in the $x$ and $x$ directions to get the semi major axes you want.

To make it more explicit and in more length, the unit square is points $(x,y)$ with $x=0,1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$, or $y=0,1$ and $0\leq x\leq 1$. To map each point on this square radially to the circle with center $(1/2,1/2)$ and radius $1/2$ we want to scale the point away from the center so that it has that distance.

We generally scale the plane away from the origin by a factor of $d$ with the map $(x,y)\mapsto (dx,dy)$. To scale away from a nonzero center $(h,k)$, first shift, then scale, then shift back: $(x,y)\mapsto (d(x-h)+h,d(y-k)+k)$ (if you have the freedom to choose your coordinate system, it behooves you to choose it so that your center of scaling is the origin, but I will follow your setup).

Here we take $d=\frac{1/2}{r}$ where $r=\sqrt{(x-1/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2}$ is the distance to the center. So our map from the square to the circle looks like

$$
(x,y)\mapsto \frac{(x-\frac{1}{2},y-\frac{1}{2})}{2\sqrt{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+(y-\frac{1}{2})^2}} + \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right).
$$

This maps all of the plane except the point $(1/2,1/2)$ onto the unit circle with that center. It maps the circumscribed square onto the circle homeomorphically.

We could also describe this map trigonometrically, as you wanted to do in the comments. For a point on the right vertical side of the square, i.e. a point $(x,y)$ with $x=1$, the angle above the center is given by $\tan \theta =x-\frac{1}{2}$ and then the point on the circle is $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta)$. The formula for $\theta$ will be similar for the other sides of the square.

If I then wanted to map this to a circle centered at the origin, I would compose it with the mapping

$$(x,y)\mapsto (x-\frac{1}{2},y-\frac{1}{2})$$.

This shift map is a homeomorphism of the plane, and when restricted to the circle gives a homeomorphism onto the image.

If I then wanted to map this unit circle centered at the origin onto an ellipse centered at the origin, I would simply scale in box $x$ and $y$ directions:

$$(x,y)\mapsto (ax,by)$$

Comment: So how would I do that....? Could you show me? Like I tried to have x,y gets mapped to cos(pi(x-1/2)), sin(-pi*y+3/2pi), which (I think) maps each midpoints of my square to the 'tips' of the unit circle, but it doesnt work for the whole square.

Comment: @Davis I have expanded my answer. Is it clearer? Would you like me to add the other sides of the square?

Comment: Doesn't this map everything to the unit circle, not the unit disc?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, based on the Box-Muller transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform:

Let the point in the square be $(x,y)$ and let $u = x - \frac12$ and  $v = y - \frac12$. Then take the point $(x',y')$ in the unit circle as

$$
x' = \sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{1}{ u^2}\right)} \cos(2\pi v) \\
y' = \sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{1}{ u^2}\right)} \sin(2\pi v) \\
$$
In fact, if $x$ and $y$ are distributed uniformly on the square, $x'$ and $y'$ will each be distributed in a normal distribution, centered on zero, with $\sigma=1$.

To create an ellipse, simply multiply $x'$ (or $y'$) by any number other than $\pm 1$.